# Combining hlookup and vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup, importrange

I am trying to import some data from one sheet to another using lookups.

I have one sheet with some data including date, name, and type of data(Puschases, Shops).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sg3fh3giXlEg1SePkwZhO_RTUEPN8WBsmAJLWSKbpkA/edit#gid=0

I then have another sheet for each team member.  I want the purchases and shops data(from sample data sheet) to import to their sheet by name, date, and type of data.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1of3wCGMZ_JEZpcxvo98Riluc5OJROMLfUN9S9LIkicE/edit#gid=0

Any thoughts on how to do this? Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("1sg3fh3giXlEg1SePkwZhO_RTUEPN8WBsmAJLWSKbpkA", "Sheet1!B1:I"),
 "select Col8,max(Col3) group by Col8 pivot Col1", 1), {3, 4}, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("1sg3fh3giXlEg1SePkwZhO_RTUEPN8WBsmAJLWSKbpkA", "Sheet1!B1:I"),
 "select Col8,max(Col"&MATCH(A2, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1sg3fh3giXlEg1SePkwZhO_RTUEPN8WBsmAJLWSKbpkA", "Sheet1!B1:I1"), 0)&") 
  group by Col8 pivot Col1", 1), {3, 4}, 0)))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! The formula works but the problem is that the Sample Data sheet gets updated every week with new data and the User data (row 1) isn't always in the same order.  Ie sometimes Amy data is in the 6th column.  Is there a way to match the user with the user in Sample Data column A?